# List of lists counting values

Tags: python

```
my_list = [
    ['user1', True, '2022-05-31 05:35:48'],
    ['user2', False, '2022-04-26 00:01:12'],
    ['user3', True, '2022-03-09 14:14:12'],
    ['user3', False, '2022-02-28 09:19:48'],
    ['user5', False, '2022-02-07 18:41:48']
]
```

I'm trying to figure out how to count the number of times true/false are in this list of lists.
Ideally I'd like to receive a structure like the following, thank you.

username counted_trues counted_falses

```
final_list = [
  ['user1', 1, 0],
  ['user2', 0, 1],
  ['user3', 1, 1],
  ['user5', 0, 1]
  ]
```

Comment: Will be easier if you make `final_dict` instead, so you can just iterate over `my_list` and increment counters.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried to accomplish this so far?

Comment: One-liner: `final_list = [[k, (t := sum(i[1] for i in l)), len(l) - t] for k, g in groupby(sorted(my_list), itemgetter(0)) if (l := list(g))]`. Imports: [`groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), [`itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter).

Comment: Please specify what format the data can have in the inner lists: is it possible for there to be more than one boolean value?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This code should work:

```
my_list = [
    ['user1', True, '2022-05-31 05:35:48'],
    ['user2', False, '2022-04-26 00:01:12'],
    ['user3', True, '2022-03-09 14:14:12'],
    ['user3', False, '2022-02-28 09:19:48'],
    ['user5', False, '2022-02-07 18:41:48']
]


output = {}
for user_info in my_list:
    if user_info[0] not in output:
        output[user_info[0]] = [0, 0]
    output[user_info[0]][0] += user_info[1]
    output[user_info[0]][1] += not(user_info[1])

final_list = []
for key, value in output.items():
    final_list.append([key, *value])

print(final_list)
```

It converts the original list (`my_list`) into a dictionary with the user's name as the key and a list of two values, the number of `True`s and the number of `False`s. This dictionary is then converted into a list.

Comment: Thank you very much.  This works as expected, I really didn't know where to begin with this.

Answer (score 1):

you can use defaultdict for easy implementation

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_list = [
    ['user1', True, '2022-05-31 05:35:48'],
    ['user2', False, '2022-04-26 00:01:12'],
    ['user3', True, '2022-03-09 14:14:12'],
    ['user3', False, '2022-02-28 09:19:48'],
    ['user5', False, '2022-02-07 18:41:48']
]

class answer_counter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pos = 0
        self.neg = 0

user2counter = defaultdict(answer_counter)

for entry in my_list:
    user, ans, _ = entry
    if ans:
        user2counter[user].pos += 1
    else:
        user2counter[user].neg += 1

final_list = []
for user in user2counter:
    final_list.append([user, user2counter[user].pos, user2counter[user].neg])

"""result
[
['user1', 1, 0], 
['user2', 0, 1], 
['user3', 1, 1], 
['user5', 0, 1]
]

"""
```

Comment: You can use `namedtuple` instead of custom class declaration

Comment: we will have to initialize the value every time. keep track of users (or check if user already exists)

Comment: So what's the problem?)

Comment: With more computations, the execution time will increase.

Comment: `defaultdict(namedtuple("AnswerCounter", "pos neg", defaults=(0, 0)))` will work exactly the same. Also you can unpack it and make code shorter: `final_list.append([user, *value])`. Also iterate over key-value pairs: `for user, value in user2counter.items()`

Comment: I forgot about arg `default_values`. this will reduce code length. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(my_list).groupby([0, 1]).size().unstack(fill_value=0).T.to_dict()
```

why don't use pandas?

output:

```
{'user1': {False: 0, True: 1},
 'user2': {False: 1, True: 0},
 'user3': {False: 1, True: 1},
 'user5': {False: 1, True: 0}}
```